# How to run plugin in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I just now started magento.I need to create the plugin in magento.I don't know how to run the plugin in magento.can anyone suggest how to run plugin in the magento.Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link to create plugin from scratch.

Link: http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5

Thanks

Comment: 'yoursite.com/test/index'  in this url what i have to replace for yoursite.com.Please can anyone suggest the url to run the plugin in magento.Advance thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr.Sunil but i have this above mentioned  problem.Can u solve this ?

Comment: I replaced yoursite.com/test/index  to localhost/magento/test/index  its redirect to home page.But i don't get the output.

Comment: when i type the url i got error message.  
Whoops, our bad...
 The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
  If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
  If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

What can you do?
      Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Store.
      Go back to the previous page.
      Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
      Follow these links to get you back on track!
      Store Home | My Account

Comment: can anyone specify how to run the plugin in the magento 1.9.2.4 ?